# passing filtered list to visible markers

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a simple list of locations,

```
    var myLocations = [
{name: "Jim's Steaks", type: "Food", latlngLoc: {lat: 39.941557, lng: -75.149310}},
{name: "Theater of the Living Arts", type: "Entertainment", latlngLoc: {lat: 39.941461, lng: -75.148745}},
{name: "Inferno Body Piercing", type: "Body Art", latlngLoc: {lat: 39.941932, lng: -75.152870}},
{name: "South Street Diner", type: "Food", latlngLoc: {lat: 39.941259, lng: -75.145176}},
{name: "Philadelphia's Magic Gardens", type: "Entertainment", latlngLoc: {lat: 39.942642, lng: -75.159285}}];
```

and I've filtered them like so,

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.pinList = ko.observableArray([]);

    myLocations.forEach(function(pinItem) {
        self.pinList.push(new Pin(pinItem));
    });

    this.currentPin = ko.observable(this.pinList()[0]);

    self.myLocations = myLocations;
    self.selectedType = ko.observable("All");
    self.filteredmyLocations = ko.computed(function(pinItem) {
        var type = self.selectedType();
        if(type === "All") {
        return self.myLocations;
        } else {
            var tempList = self.myLocations.slice();
            return tempList.filter(function(myLocation) {
                return myLocation.type === type;
            });
        }
    });
    this.setPin = function(clickedPin) {
        largeInfoWindow.marker = null;
        self.currentPin(clickedPin);
        showInfoWindow(clickedPin.marker, largeInfoWindow);
        loadData(clickedPin.name);
        console.log(clickedPin);
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

my markers are placed like so,

```
function makeMarkers(i) {
    var position = myLocations[i].latlngLoc;
    var name = myLocations[i].name;
    var type = myLocations[i].type;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: position,
            name: name,
            type: type,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: defaultIcon,
            id: i
    });

    markers.push(marker);
```

now what I can't wrap my head around is filtering the markers to match the filtered list. Any help would be great, been stuck for a week.

Answer (score 0):

Without your full code I had to make some changes/assumptions to get a working example so this might not fully fit what you're trying to do. Hopefully the concept is useful regardless. I would structure the filtering computed like this so that it's not necessarily returning anything, but does trigger a refresh of the map any time it gets computed. (note - this must be a normal computed not a pureComputed)

```
  this.filteredmyLocations = ko.computed(function(){
      var type = self.selectedType();
      var pins = self.pinList();
      if(type !== "All") {
          pins = pins.filter(function(myLocation) {
              return myLocation.type === type;
          });
      }
      self.makeMarkers(pins);
  });
```

Then the makeMarkers function would take the passed-in array of locations and update the map with those instead of going back to the original array. Full example: [https://jsfiddle.net/a52wa21c/](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/a52wa21c/)

Comment: I will try that, here's the full repo: github.com/danaschenbach/neighbor-map in case you come up with something else.

Comment: I should of left link to git repo the first time. Gotta do a lot of editing to tie it all back together...but still great info

Comment: could you look at my GitHub repo, filter works but not for my application. I'm needing to filter existing list, have list filter update markers, list & markers have to be clickable to show infoWindow & wiki info. trying to take the output from list filter & pass that into a filter for the markers. [link](http://github.com/danaschenbach/neighbor-map) thank you for your time

Comment: @phily_phreak I'll certainly try to take a look at it today if I have some spare time.

Comment: @phily_phreak Here's an updated fiddle using your github code. The click events seem a little wonky still but I'm not sure what they're supposed to do exactly. https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/a52wa21c/7/